# Javascript String return inside script tag

Tags: javascript

I'm not so good with regex or trying to return the side part of a string. Can someone help me figure this out.  I have a demo below.

```
str = "<html><head><script>var x = '123';</script></head></html>";

console.log(str)
// should return var x = '123';
```

Comment: I don't really understand why this question has been down graded, I personnaly wouldn't have the idea to look for "strip tags" to find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone wrote a very good regex for stripping tags:

```
var strippedStr = str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
console.log(strippedStr);
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit with it and found a way with match using groups:

```
str.match(/(>)([^><]+)(<\/)/m)[2]
```

result = "var x = '123';"

=> a range (2nd group) beginning by ">" (1st group) and ending with "var x = '123';

I am not sure it'll cover all the cases...